# Custom content before post content

Tags: loop, content-restriction, post-content

I am using this code to insert custom content after title and before content. How can i limit it to only "post" not pages and custom post types.

```
function theme_slug_filter_the_content( $content ) {
$custom_content = 'YOUR CONTENT GOES HERE';
$custom_content .= $content;
return $custom_content;} add_filter( 'the_content', 'theme_slug_filter_the_content' );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the post type of the current post via [`get_post_type`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_type):

```
function theme_slug_filter_the_content( $content ) {
    if( 'post' == get_post_type() ){
        $custom_content = 'YOUR CONTENT GOES HERE';
        return $custom_content . $content;
    }
    return $content;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'theme_slug_filter_the_content' );
```